# Comparing a Listbox Selected Item

Tags: vb.net, listbox

My code:

```
If Form3.lstOrder.SelectedItem = "Chicken" Then
            total -= ChickenPrice
            Form3.txtTotal.Text = total
End If
```

The program is supposed to read the selected item in the `ListBox` and compare to see if it matches 'chicken'; if it *is* chicken, the price of chicken is then removed from the order total.

However this does not work, can anyone help?

Comment: How are you generating the `ListBox.Items` collection? Didn't you set each Item's `ValueMember` to the value of the object visually represented by the `DisplayMember` (the string `"Chicken"`, here)?

Comment: @jimi each item is put into the listbox via a button

Comment: With a Button click you execute code. What is this code doing? In other words, how are you generating the `ListBox.Items` collection? Or, what is the source of the data used to fill the List? Have you associated a Value to the object *description*?

Comment: @jimi ' Dim price As Single

        lstOrder.Items.Add("Chicken")
        price = 2.99
        total += price

        Me.txtTotal.Text = FormatCurrency(total)'

Comment: Edit your question to add the details needed to understand your context. Don't post it in a comment. Click the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60003533/edit) link to modify the question's content. Also, I suppose your ListBox doesn't contain just one item.

Comment: @Jimi Ok, the list box contains items, that when a button is pressed the item are added. At the bottom there is a label that will add the sum of all of the items together to give me a total. However, if I want to delete the item the price that the item was that has been deleted does not reduce and stays the same.

Comment: As already mentioned, you need to post the code involved in these operations and give details that about your context. What I can derive from your comment, is that you have two ListBoxes that need to *cooperate*. Edit your question, explain the context and post the related code. You have skipped the SO Tour, but you have to read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What do you mean by `this does not work`? That doesn't help us help you. We can't read your mind. Edit your question to include the necessary information as described in [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: The title of your question could use some love, too.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: I assume total is a numeric type. .Text expects a string. Thus the comment above.

Answer (score 1):

The `.SelectedItem` property is of type Object, (as opposed to String), and you're trying to compare it directly to a String.

Do this instead:

```
If Form3.lstOrder.SelectedItem.ToString() = "Chicken" Then
            total -= ChickenPrice
            Form3.txtTotal.Text = total
End If
```

Here's a reference that may help, as well:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Good point about the Object. I would have upvoted for the dog alone.